# Decoding the characters received from serial port

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port, ascii

I am receiving data from a serial port connected to a card reader.
I use the following code to receive data:

```
        private string _recValAppendForReader = "";
        private void _comPort_SerialDataReceivedCustom(byte[] data)
        {
           _recValAppendForReader = _recValAppendForReader + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
```

But very rarely(one in 10000s), I am getting character `'p'` instead of `'0'`, `'q'` instead of `'1'`,`'r'` instead of `'2'` and so on, till `'y'` instead of `'9'`. Its must to related to decoding because when i checked in HyperTerminal its coming properly.
I have checked with device manufacturers and they confirmed with ASCII encoding.

What may be the issue?

Comment: Use Async Read not Sync.  Sync you can have errors.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but check if the number of stop bits is set correctly for your card reader - as long as it's a real serial connections, not an emulated via USB.